# Solving Markowitz style portfolio optimization with Rmosek

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio, mosek

I am trying to understand how mosek works and formulated a formulated a simple min xT*Sigma*x

I use the example data from the Rmosek codebook and tried to formulate the problem in conic form.

The quadratic term is substituted by t following the guides on the mosek website. t is then minimized.

```
# Example of input
n      <- 8
w      <- 1.0
mu     <- c(0.07197349, 0.15518171, 0.17535435, 0.0898094, 0.42895777, 0.39291844, 0.32170722, 0.18378628)
x0     <- c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
GT     <- rbind( c(0.30758, 0.12146, 0.11341, 0.11327, 0.17625, 0.11973, 0.10435, 0.10638),
                 c(0.     , 0.25042, 0.09946, 0.09164, 0.06692, 0.08706, 0.09173, 0.08506),
                 c(0.     , 0.     , 0.19914, 0.05867, 0.06453, 0.07367, 0.06468, 0.01914),
                 c(0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.20876, 0.04933, 0.03651, 0.09381, 0.07742),
                 c(0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.36096, 0.12574, 0.10157, 0.0571 ),
                 c(0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.21552, 0.05663, 0.06187),
                 c(0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.22514, 0.03327),
                 c(0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.2202 ) )`

library("Rmosek")

# Sample covariance matrix
Sigma <- t(GT)%*%GT

# Number of assets
n <- ncol(GT)

# Problem definition
prob <- list(sense="min")

# Objective: We're minimizing t, which represents portfolio variance
prob$c <- c(rep(0, n), 1)

# Conic constraint: t >= x^T Sigma x
prob$F <- rbind(
  cbind(Matrix(0.0,nrow=1,ncol=n), 1), 
  cbind(GT, Matrix(0, n, 1))
)
prob$g <- c(rep(0, n),1)

prob$cones <- matrix(list("QUAD", 1+n, NULL), nrow=3, ncol=1)
rownames(prob$cones) <- c("type","dim","conepar")

# Linear constraint: Sum of x[i] = 1
prob$A <- Matrix(c(rep(1, n), 0), 1)

prob$bc <- rbind(blc=1,
                 buc=1)

# Bounds: 0 <= x[i] <= 1, 0 <= t
prob$bx <- rbind(blx=c(rep(0, n + 1)), 
                 bux=c(rep(1, n), Inf))

# Solve the problem
r <- mosek(prob,list(verbose=10))

xTestMosekSimpleMinVarConic <- r$sol$itr$xx[1:n]

stddevsol <- r$sol$itr$xx[n+1]

stddevcalc <- (t(xTestMosekSimpleMinVarConic)%*%Sigma%*%xTestMosekSimpleMinVarConic)^0.5
expret <- drop(mu %*% xTestMosekSimpleMinVarConic)

print(sprintf("xTestMosekSimpleMinVarConic"))
print(sprintf("Expected return: %.4e Std. deviation solver: %.4e Std. deviation calc: %.4e", round(expret,5), round(stddevsol,5), stddevcalc))
print(round(xTestMosekSimpleMinVarConic,5))
```

When I solve this the result is:

```
[1] "Expected return: 1.7350e-01 Std. deviation solver: 1.0214e+00 Std. deviation calc: 2.0803e-01"
[1] 0.13469 0.14807 0.29008 0.23863 0.00000 0.11060 0.07793 0.00000
```

However when I solve the same problem as a quadratic problem i get:

```
[1] "Expected return: 1.6625e-01 Std. deviation: 2.0373e-01 "
[1] 0.11332 0.11437 0.30221 0.18154 0.00000 0.05632 0.04519 0.18706
```

the code:

```
library("Rmosek")

Sigma <- t(GT)%*%GT
# Number of assets
n <- length(mu)

# Define the QP problem
prob <- list(sense = "min")

# Convert the lower triangular part of the covariance matrix Sigma 
# into the required list format for qobj
i_indices <- c()
j_indices <- c()
values <- c()

for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:i) {
    if (Sigma[i, j] != 0) {
      i_indices <- append(i_indices, i)
      j_indices <- append(j_indices, j)
      values <- append(values, Sigma[i, j])
    }
  }
}

prob$qobj <- list(i = i_indices, j = j_indices, v = values)

prob$c <-c(rep(0,n))

# Equality constraint for sum of weights: 1^T * x = 1
prob$A <- matrix(rep(1, n), 1)
prob$bc <- rbind(blc = 1, buc = 1)

# Non-negativity constraints on asset weights: x >= 0
prob$bx <- rbind(blx = rep(0, n), bux = rep(Inf, n))

# Solve the problem
solution <- mosek(prob,list(verbose=1))

xTestMosekSimpleQuad <- solution$sol$itr$xx
stddev <- (t(xTestMosekSimpleQuad)%*%Sigma%*%xTestMosekSimpleQuad)^0.5
expret <- drop(mu %*% xTestMosekSimpleQuad)

print(sprintf("xTestMosekSimpleQuad"))
print(sprintf("Expected return: %.4e Std. deviation: %.4e ", round(expret,5), round(stddev,5)))
print(round(xTestMosekSimpleQuad,5))
```

The same result I get when I solve the problem with CVXR using the standard solver but also with the mosek-solver

CXVR code:

```
library("CVXR")

Sigma <- t(GT)%*%GT

## Form problem
w <- Variable(n)
ret <- t(mu) %*% w
risk <- quad_form(w, Sigma)
constraints <- list(w >= 0, sum(w) == 1)
objective <- risk
prob <- Problem(Minimize(objective), constraints)
result <- solve(prob, solver='MOSEK', verbose = TRUE)
risk_data <- result$getValue(sqrt(risk))
ret_data <- result$getValue(ret)
w_data <- result$getValue(w)
```

CVXR is handling it as a conic problem:

Problem
Name                   :
Objective sense        : minimize
Type                   : CONIC (conic optimization problem)
Constraints            : 19
Affine conic cons.     : 0
Disjunctive cons.      : 0
Cones                  : 1
Scalar variables       : 19
Matrix variables       : 0
Integer variables      : 0

Optimizer started.
Presolve started.
Linear dependency checker started.
Linear dependency checker terminated.
Eliminator started.
Freed constraints in eliminator : 0
Eliminator terminated.
Eliminator - tries                  : 1                 time                   : 0.00
Lin. dep.  - tries                  : 1                 time                   : 0.00
Lin. dep.  - primal attempts        : 1                 successes              : 1
Lin. dep.  - dual attempts          : 0                 successes              : 0
Lin. dep.  - primal deps.           : 0                 dual deps.             : 0
Presolve terminated. Time: 0.00
Optimizer  - threads                : 12
Optimizer  - solved problem         : the primal
Optimizer  - Constraints            : 10
Optimizer  - Cones                  : 1
Optimizer  - Scalar variables       : 18                conic                  : 10
Optimizer  - Semi-definite variables: 0                 scalarized             : 0
Factor     - setup time             : 0.00
Factor     - dense det. time        : 0.00              GP order time          : 0.00
Factor     - nonzeros before factor : 54                after factor           : 54
Factor     - dense dim.             : 0                 flops                  : 1.20e+03
ITE PFEAS    DFEAS    GFEAS    PRSTATUS   POBJ              DOBJ              MU       TIME
0   1.0e+00  6.0e-01  1.4e+00  0.00e+00   0.000000000e+00   -3.973982284e-01  1.0e+00  0.00
1   4.1e-01  2.5e-01  1.1e-01  7.52e-01   4.724270646e-02   -3.621647720e-01  4.1e-01  0.00
2   1.5e-01  8.9e-02  2.3e-02  2.20e+00   3.208365717e-02   -4.069524762e-02  1.5e-01  0.00
3   2.0e-02  1.2e-02  1.1e-03  1.39e+00   4.349220651e-02   3.528925879e-02   2.0e-02  0.00
4   4.1e-03  2.4e-03  9.7e-05  1.05e+00   4.314371279e-02   4.153013503e-02   4.1e-03  0.00
5   6.2e-04  3.7e-04  7.0e-06  1.01e+00   4.148713867e-02   4.126481240e-02   6.2e-04  0.00
6   7.6e-05  4.6e-05  3.0e-07  1.00e+00   4.150471852e-02   4.147717911e-02   7.6e-05  0.00
7   1.0e-05  6.2e-06  1.5e-08  1.00e+00   4.150531100e-02   4.150163293e-02   1.0e-05  0.00
8   2.5e-07  1.5e-07  5.7e-11  1.00e+00   4.150536024e-02   4.150527034e-02   2.5e-07  0.00
9   5.1e-10  3.0e-10  5.0e-15  1.00e+00   4.150536306e-02   4.150536288e-02   5.0e-10  0.00
Optimizer terminated. Time: 0.00

Interior-point solution summary
Problem status  : PRIMAL_AND_DUAL_FEASIBLE
Solution status : OPTIMAL
Primal.  obj: 4.1505363060e-02    nrm: 1e+00    Viol.  con: 2e-10    var: 0e+00    cones: 0e+00
Dual.    obj: 4.1505362883e-02    nrm: 2e-01    Viol.  con: 0e+00    var: 1e-10    cones: 0e+00
Optimizer summary
Optimizer                 -                        time: 0.00
Interior-point          - iterations : 9         time: 0.00
Basis identification  -                        time: 0.00
Primal              - iterations : 0         time: 0.00
Dual                - iterations : 0         time: 0.00
Clean primal        - iterations : 0         time: 0.00
Clean dual          - iterations : 0         time: 0.00
Simplex                 -                        time: 0.00
Primal simplex        - iterations : 0         time: 0.00
Dual simplex          - iterations : 0         time: 0.00
Mixed integer           - relaxations: 0         time: 0.00

Where is my mistake in the Mosek code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that your comment says

```
# Conic constraint: t >= x^T Sigma x
```

where `x^T Sigma x = x^T GT^T GT x = || GT x ||_2^2`, but then you use the quadratic cone and essentially get

```
t >= || GT x ||_2
```

which corresponds to `t >= sqrt(x^T Sigma x)`. This difference is fine if `t` only appears in the objective (in fact, it is beneficial, since it gives you better scaling), but you need to be aware of the difference when you interpret the result.

Second thing I noticed is that you have

```
prob$g <- c(rep(0, n),1)
```

but this adds a constant `1` to last entry of the conic constraint essentially giving you `t >= || GT x + e_n ||_2` where e_n is a unit vector. Try using

```
prob$g <- c(rep(0, n+1))
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, it was the 1 in prob$g, now it gives me the same weights as CVXR. Regarding $t, I basically minimise the std instead of variance, correct? so t >= sqrt(x^T Sigma x).  In the examples on mosek.com, they use the rotated quadratic cone when using the variance in the objective. What I dont get is, in their "conic cheet sheet they define t ≥ xTΣx (t,LTx) ∈ Qk+1 which was what I used. max x αTx−δxTΣx max x αTx−δr
(0.5, r, LT x) ∈ Qk+2 for Risk-return. But in their examples online: https://docs.mosek.com/latest/rmosek/case-studies-portfolio.html#equation-doc-markowitz-model-slippage